# SQL Server 2008 will not detect whitespace in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This sql does not return any records:

```
SELECT [doi]
FROM [BESC].[dbo].[Publications]
where doi like '% journal%'
```

but this code returns records with internal excess spaces:

```
SELECT [doi]
FROM [Publications]
where doi like '%journal%'
```

returns (for example): '10.1371/  journal.pone.0012947'

How can I select for these records with the spaces?

Additional clue -- this sql

```
SELECT [doi]
FROM [Publications]
where doi like '10.1371/  journal.pone.0012947'
```

also returns no records (copy and pasted directly from the record, in case it was some odd unseen character)

Can anyone give me a clue what to try next?

Comment: That's might not be a normal space in the data. Make sure your query tool or web browser (if this is in a page) isn't showing a table, non-breaking space character, or similar as a space in the bugger.

Comment: What does the following return? `SELECT [doi], Cast([doi] as varbinary(100)) FROM [Publications] where doi like '%journal%'`

Comment: Try running a ad-hoc query without the whitespace with `CAST(doi AS varbinary(MAX))` to see the hex value.  I would expect other than 0x20 for the whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

Turned out to be a carriage return in a field that should never, ever have a return, even accidentally. (what can I say...time to review code and procedures!)